# Android play audio after page loaded

Tags: java, android

After go to go to next activity, I got this code for my next activity

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio);
mp.start();
```

The audio play before the page loaded, is there possible to let the audio play after the page loaded?

Comment: Yes of course. Just call a function when the page finishes the loading and then inside the function you can have the code segment to play audio. The question is not too detailed. Please add more code to clarify your exact implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when an activity is created, the onCreate method is called, then onStart and then onResume. you can use this methods. but if you are working with network or other time consuming operations to populate your views, you should place your code in the listener which is called when the operation is finished. anyway you should give me more detail!